# Pandas dataframe to array with .values gives nan

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, nan, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to drop a column and then use the remainder for some statistical tests. When I do this and test the minimum value I get:

```
X = dtf_scaled_train.drop('y_train_scaled', axis=1)

print(np.min(X))
```

which gives me:

```
OverallQual               -2.500000
GrLivArea                 -1.721519
GarageCars                -2.000000
GarageArea                -1.892216
TotalBsmtSF               -1.972084
FullBath                  -2.000000
YearBuilt                 -2.108696
YearRemodAdd              -1.189189
LotFrontage               -2.333333
MSSubClass                -0.600000
MSSubClass_cluster_mean   -1.000000
MSSubClass_cluster_min     0.000000
dtype: float64
```

which is great! But when I convert this to array and get the minimum like this:

```
X = dtf_scaled_train.drop('y_train_scaled', axis=1).values

print(np.min(X))
```

I get:

```
nan
```

What is going on here...?

Comment: Have you tried with `print(np.min(X).values)` ?

Comment: @abokey That returns me valid numbers. I need the arrays as I will pass it into some stats tests and they can't use nan values

Comment: HI, what do you mean by *That returns me valid numbers*?

Comment: print(np.min(X).values) returns a non-nan value